# Create Azure SQL db, incorrect syntax near MAXSIZE

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to create new Azure SQL database as copy of old db with the following sql script:

```
CREATE DATABASE [abc-456] AS COPY OF [abc-123] ( MAXSIZE = 500 MB, SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'basic', EDITION = 'basic' )
```

But in result I see `Incorrect syntax near 'MAXSIZE'.`

If I remove `MAXSIZE` option then it works fine.

If I remove `AS COPY OF dbname` it also works fine.

How can I fix that issue?

Comment: Use `AS COPY OF` to get a copy, then `ALTER DATABASE MODIFY` to set the max size. If that's not possible because the current max size exceeds what's allowed on basic, then I'm guessing what you want can't be done through a copy, and requires doing a data import/export dance.

Comment: @JeroenMostert What's syntax? `ALTER DATABASE [abc-456] ( MODIFY MAXSIZE = 500 MB )`?

Comment: You can look up the [proper syntax yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current).

Comment: The following documentation does not state you can assign a max size as part of the statement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-copy